# Using regex in unix

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching

I need to print "some text" when the env I set (MY_DIR) in this case doesn't have the word "property"

I am doing this and I couldn't do it. Can someone help ?

```
> setenv MY_DIR property.ram
> grep -v $MY_DIR property
grep: property: No such file or directory
```

I also tried this,

```
if [ "$MY_DIR" == ^\(\(?!property\).\)*$ ]; then 
      echo "Some text" 
fi
```

This is not working too

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting my question ?

Comment: Ah, so many things wrong here. Your seem to use csh or tcsh as your interactive shell. Your script extract looks like a POSIX-style shell, but you're trying to match against a regex, which could work in bash using `[[` and `=~`, but not `[` and `==`. The `grep` command searches files or stdin. No idea what `.ram` is about. Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question, as well as the description of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Both will help make your question answerable. Explain your *goal*, so we can correct underlying assumptions, too.

Comment: @ghoti.. If you don't understand leave! Others who understood will answer

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
echo "$MY_DIR"|grep -v property
```

Sample

```
sh-4.3$ MY_DIR=property.ram 
sh-4.3$ echo "$MY_DIR"|grep -v property 
sh-4.3$ echo "$?" 
1 
sh-4.3$ MY_DIR=some_other_val 
sh-4.3$ echo "$MY_DIR"|grep -v property 
some_other_val
sh-4.3$ echo "$?" 
0
```

Use in a script by utilizing `$?`. As seen in the example above, `$?` will return `0` if the grep command returns a result. ELse it will return 1.

```
sh-4.3$ cat so21.sh
MY_DIR=property.ram 
echo "$MY_DIR"|grep -v property 
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ];then
 echo "property found"
else
 echo "property not found"
fi
sh-4.3$ 
sh-4.3$ ./so21.sh 
property found
```

Comment: if [ "$MY_DIR" == ^\(\(?!property\).\)*$ ]; then
     echo "Some text"
fi

Comment: Is there a way I can do something like this ?

Comment: I have got a better answer, > if [ "property" != ${MY_DIR,0,8}" ]; then